# If element found, hide only the element after

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

So let's say I have this scenario of articles: 
I have a photo in the left and the content of the article right after the image. 
In the content area I have a reservation button.
If the article is reserved, then it will be displayed a small image over the bottom of the photo (transparent written "Reserved").
This stuff is all done.

What I want to do next is to remove the hyperlink-button "Reserve" from the article if it's reserved. Should look like this:

1. -NormalIMG- [Reservation-Button]
2. -NormalIMG- [Reservation-Button]
3. -ReservedIMG- *
4. -NormalIMG- [Reservation-Button]
5. -ReservedIMG- *
6. -NormalIMG- [Reservation-Button]
   and so on.
   **here's no reservation button*

So it's something like this: 
    
    
     
     
      
       Reserve

```
<!-- reserved article -->
 <div class="article">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-reserved"><img src="reserved.jpg" /></div>
   <div class="content">
     <a href="#" class="reserveLink">Reserve</a>
   </div>
 </div>
<!-- reserved article //-->

<!-- unreserved article -->
<div class="article">
 <div class="image"></div>
 <div class="image-reserved"></div>
  <div class="content">
   <a href="#" class="reserveLink">Reserve</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- unreserved article //-->

<!-- reserved article -->
 <div class="article">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-reserved"><img src="reserved.jpg" /></div>
   <div class="content">
     <a href="#" class="reserveLink">Reserve</a>
   </div>
 </div>
<!-- reserved article //-->
```

I tried with jQuery something like this:

```
if(!($('.image-reserved').find(img))) {
    $('.reserveLink').addCSS('display', 'none');
}
```

But I got all the "Reserve" links removed...

I realized that I need something that should apply that CSS attribute only after the element 'img' was found. 
After that, it should continue the search and apply it when it has to.

I lost all my day trying to figure out a way to get out of this by implementing different structures (using find, has, next, etc.) similar to the above example... but no success.

I'm posting here as a last resort, my hope is completely lost to something that seemed to be so easy to implement...

IMPORTANT NOTE: I know the structure looks weird and it might be really hard for what I want to be implemented, but I am not allowed to modify any code that was written already.

Comment: And where exactly is `.reserveLink` ?

Comment: This would be so much more straightforward if the image were a sibling (or aunt/uncle) of the thing to be hidden.  Then you could say like `$('img[src="reserved.jpg"]+.content').hide();`.

Comment: I think that the `.reserveLink` class is missing in your `<a>` tags in `.content`...

Comment: Yes, that's true. ".reserveLink" it's the class which was missing from <a>. I edited now the code.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you. I'm really sorry that I can't rate you because I have below 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud iterate over each image-reserved :

```
// For each image reserved
$(".image-reserved").each(function(){
    // Count the children
    var count = $(this).children("img").length;
    // If there's a child (The reserved img), then we delete the following links
    if(count > 0){
        $(this).next().children(".reserveLink").hide();  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.image-reserved').next().hide()`

Comment: It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.content').filter(function(){
    return $(this).prev('div.image-reserved').find('img').length;
}).find('a').remove();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eVtAB/).

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 0):

`$('div.image-reserved:not(:empty)+.content a.reserveLink')` will find all `.image-reserved` divs that have content, and select the `.reserveLink` links in the `.content` element after them.